# Has anyone encountered Bundles/MsAjax error: PRM_ParserErrorDetails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 135529 in http://localhost:12719/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=j9o3qlKdc_Bj_LUejHQUBA53P8zxsxFJpe4eufPsc6I1

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'PRM_ParserErrorDetails' of undefined or null reference

I am emulating IE8 from IE11.

I am using .net 4.5.1 with the default webform template.

I was requested to support IE 8.

The setup is simple - a Webform with a Listview which binds to a List returned from the Data Access Layer.
This process works fine on another page that does exactly the same routine.

The Webform is using bootstrap 3.3.4 and Jquery 1.11.4, the extra respond.js and html5shiv.js that are recommended to support IE8+.  This ALMOST worked. Except in this case.

I get this msajaxjs error and I'm wondering if anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: localhost links are pointless and unhelpful. can you show the code?

Comment: What caused the error? I got this error when clicking a linkbutton on a grid inside of an `UpdatePanel` that downloads a file. If it's something like that, I can probably help you.

Comment: @TonyL. I am getting the same issue with the same scenario mentioned by you

Answer (score 0):

i was struggling with that error my self. At the end i found out that a:

```
Response.Write("message")
```

i inserted in the code for the async postback (used for debugging purpose) was blocking the request and raising this error. Just commented it and problem resolved. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If have your export button is under an UpdatePanel move it out. The following worked for me.

e.g.

Before

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
```

After

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />  
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```